# How to save locally my current HTML / Javascript page (using Javascript / PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php

I've a simple HTML / Javascript page and I'd like to give to my user the ability to save the code of my current page that is a simple HTML / Javascript page.

I'm thinking something like right-click + "Save as"(Ctrl+S) + "Select All" (Ctrl+A) + Copy (Ctrl+C) + Paste (Ctrl-V) in some file locally

I'm using PHP ....

Any suggestion (or, better, example ..), will be appreciated ...

Cesaee

Comment: How is the user going to access this data.. if they are already in a browser they can just hit ctrl + s

Comment: Yes, ctrl+s already saves the html page as a local file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's static page which doesn't need user input or data, the easiest thing that comes to mind is linking to a ZIP file. You could link to a text file too so that it's easier for the user to copy and paste. But generally speaking, if you link to a resource the user's browser understands, the browser will try to render the content and make it a little trickier for the user to save.

Alternatively, as Al.G. pointed out below, you can set a header in PHP to download the webpage rather than render it. You can do this as follows:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.html"');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ...
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-wrap">
    ....
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever the user visits the PHP page, it will download all of the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript after the initial closing PHP tag. Perhaps you could link to the page they're viewing and say "download this page", which links to a copy with that PHP bit at the top?

Comment: It's not difficult at all - just send a Content-disposition header.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. My answer is updated to reflect that useful tidbit.